# How to consider putting data into one sheet based on values from cells in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a little problem writing a module that will write some data from one Sheet that has many columns, filter only the columns i want and input it into a new sheet inside the same workbook and worksheet.

What i need to do is fix the process that write data into new sheet, as it looks like its not working.

For example:
Sheet A has columns with data :
A B C D E F G and for exeample: A = name, B = email, etc.

```
I want take for example only A, B, D, E, F into a new sheet and order like this:
A = A (new sheet)
B = B (new sheet)
D = C (new sheet)
```

The only reason i'm doing this is because i need to compare if a cell isnt empty, then just flag it in the new sheet, only for i'll know which cells have values and work on that.

for example:
Column A and B will have values, but sometimes only C and E have values, so on the new sheet it will recieve an OK like flag.

My module is very simple:

*My if statements doesnt work well and i cant figure out what the problem is.

```
        Sub transport()
        Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
        Dim i As Integer

        'inputs
        Dim usr_name As String
        Dim usr_email As String
        Dim usr_id As String
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim cell_p1
        Dim cell_p2
        Dim cell_p3
        Dim cell_p4
        Dim cell_p5
        Dim cell_p6
        Dim cell_p7

        'outuputs
        Dim tgt_usr As String
        Dim tgt_email As String
        Dim tgt_usrid As String
        Dim p1 As String
        Dim p2 As String
        Dim p3 As String
        Dim p4 As String
        Dim p5 As String
        Dim p6 As String
        Dim p7 As String


        'results

        total = Worksheets("meta").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To total

                cell_p1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("K" & i)
                cell_p2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("L" & i)
                cell_p3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("M" & i)
                cell_p4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("N" & i)
                cell_p5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("O" & i)
                cell_p6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("P" & i)
                cell_p7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("Q" & i)

                p1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "D").Value
                p2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "E").Value
                p3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "F").Value
                p4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "G").Value
                p5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "H").Value
                p6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "I").Value
                p7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "J").Value

                usr_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("B" & i).Value
                usr_email = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("A" & i).Value
                usr_id = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("T" & i).Value

                tgt_usr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "A").Value
                tgt_email = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "B").Value
                tgt_usrid = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "C").Value

                tgt_usr = usr_name
                tgt_email = usr_email
                tgt_usrid = usr_id

                If cell_p1 <> "" Then
                    p1 = "'1"
                        If cell_p2 <> "" Then
                            p2 = "'1"
                        If cell_p3 <> "" Then
                            p3 = "'1"
                        If cell_p4 <> "" Then
                            p4 = "'1"
                        If cell_p5 <> "" Then
                            p5 = "'1"
                        If cell_p6 <> "" Then
                                p6 = "'1"
                            If cell_p7 <> "" Then
                                p7 = "'1"
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
            Next i

   End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: The `If` statement in your code is nested. If `cell_p1` is blank, it will not check `cell_p2` and so on. Is this really you wanted?

Comment: BTW, p1~p6 are only string variables. You should `Dim p1 As Range` then `Set p1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "D")` so that the value you assigned goes to the cell. Otherwise it will stay in the memory only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanations inside the code.

```
Sub transport()
    'So sad that You set up an object without using it :/
    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    'Integer isnt bad, not good enough :P
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'inputs
    Dim usr_name As String
    Dim usr_email As String
    Dim usr_id As String
    Dim total As Integer
    'I prefer using an array, easier to call and loop
    Dim cell() As Variant

    'outuputs
    Dim tgt_usr_rng As Range
    Dim tgt_email_rng As Range
    Dim tgt_usrid_rng As Range
    'Dim it as an 2-D array, easier to give values into range
    Dim p(1 To 1, 1 To 7) As String

    'results

    total = Worksheets("meta").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To total

        'You can feed a range into a variant array directly
        cell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("K" & i, "Q" & i).Value
        '#Notice#
        'Since we give it a 1-row, 7-column range, the array is a 2-D array with 1 row and 7 columns.
        'So calling the first value by cell( 1 , 1), the second by cell( 1 , 2 ) and so on.

        '##### Note
        usr_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("B" & i).Value
        usr_email = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("A" & i).Value
        usr_id = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("T" & i).Value

        Set tgt_usr_rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "A")
        Set tgt_email_rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "B")
        Set tgt_usrid_rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "C")

        tgt_usr_rng = usr_name
        tgt_email_rng = usr_email
        tgt_usrid_rng = usr_id
        '#####

        'This will check the 7 columns one by one. If there is a value, gives a flag
        For j = 1 To 7
            If cell(1, j) <> "" Then
                p(1, j) = "'1"
            Else
                p(1, j) = ""
            End If
        Next j
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Range("D" & i).Resize(1, 7) = p
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note: If you won't need tgt_usr_rng anymore, you can simply coding like
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "A").Value = usr_name`
Or even assigning a range value to another range.

Because that it seems you only use the variable twice each loop, first for reading data, second for giving data. You can read and give the data at the same time, cheaper for both time and memory. Therefore, if you don't need to make other operations, the block can be written as

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "A") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("B" & i).Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "B") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("A" & i).Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("transport").Cells(i, "C") = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("meta").Range("T" & i).Value
```

Comment: Brilliant and awesome solution! I'm new in VBA (i think i have one month that i've managed to use it) and this helped and teached me a lot! Thank you @newacc2240

Comment: Hi @C.Carvalho, if you still have several questions, feel free to leave a comment here. If you are clear now, congrats and please select my answer for flagging this topic as solved, thank you.

Comment: Hello @newacc2240, thank you for your support! I've made a little fix inside the for j, i needed to clear P before writing, so i just added p = "" before checking fields so it wouldn't flood my sheet. 
Edit: flagged it. thanks!

Comment: Sure, my fault, it is surely should be wiped before we assigning value in it.